# Is there any way to scroll to the left/right of a screen in rpgle?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am facing issue in adding more fields into the screen of RPGLE to the right hand side

Don't have any idea how to do it.... suggest anything.

Comment: What kind of display are we talking about? In general, avoid forcing the user to scroll horizontally. It's one of the worst UI anti-patterns I have ever experienced. Otherwise, fields in a display file naturally wrap at the rightmost position to the leftmost at the next line. This continues until all positions are shown. This is not a feature of RPGLE, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about 5250 green screen, the fact you may be doing so from RPG is mostly immaterial.

**Short answer**
No, there's no concept of horizonal scrolling in the 5250 protocol.

**Long answer**
There are various ways to deal with "wider" amounts of data to display.

- It's 2023...consider a web UI instead of 5250.  Any option, include
  using RPG as a CGI language would provide a much more flexible UI.
- Define your 5250 screen as 27x132 instead of the default 24x80.
- Consider "foldable" subfile rows.  Instead of being limited by the amount of data you can fit on 1 subfile row (ex 125 characters) Your subfile record can be larger (ex 250, 375) and will be shown folded (wrapped) across multiple lines on screen.  The user can be allow to control if just the first line or all the lines are displayed. (`SFLFOLD`/`SFLDROP`/`SFLMODE` DDS keywords)

That pretty much covers the "easy" options that take advantage of what the IBM i platform supports.  If you really need to scroll a 5250 screen horizontally, it can be simulated...but you'll be pretty much on your own.

Consider a 27x132 5250 screen in which want rows 5-24 to scroll horizontally; as done by the `DSPSPLF` command.

If the data is for display only, it's pretty easy.  The DDS for the screen simply defines a 20 row subfile with a single 132 character field.  Or do without the subfile and have 20 separate 132 character fields defined.  When the user scrolls horizontally, you program figures out what should be display and loads the lines to the display file.

A screen that allows the user to make changes isn't that much more difficult; if you're dealing with string data ala the `EDTF` command.

Actually, if you dealing with string data anyway...see if you can just make use of `EDTF` rather than re-invent the wheel.

But if you're a glutton for punishment, and you really, really want a horizontally scrollable screen with individually editable fields...

The good news is it can be done, exhibit A from the DBU application sold by ProData.
[image]

The bad news is that in 25yrs of working on the platform, I've never needed to build such an application.

My first thought is that you'd want to make use of the [Dynamic Screen Manager (DSM) API's](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/dsm.htm)

And while I've made use of one or two of those in my career, mainly to check that a users 5250 session was configured to support a 27x132 screen.  I've never built an entire screen with them.

Additionally, after a little digging into the DBU application it appears that it doesn't seem to be using the QSNAPI *SRVPGM that contains the DSM API's.  Instead, the app appears to be using the regular RPG & DDS functionality, namely the `EXFMT` op-code.  Which would seem indicate that the app is embedding 5250 control characters directly into the data.  Playing with the 5250 data stream is not for the faint of heart.  I suspect the DBU app simply predates the availability of the DSM APIs.  Given that the DSM API support "[Low-Level Screen I/O Services APIs"](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/dsm1.htm).

> The low-level screen I/O services APIs provide a direct interface to
> the 5250 data stream commands and user-defined data streams for
> performing basic screen I/O operations. For detailed information about
> the results and interactions of these operations, see the following
> 5250 data stream documentation:
>
> 5250 Functions Reference, SA21-9247. This manual is not accessible
> online, but can be ordered from the IBM® Publications Center
>
> 5494 Remote Control Unit Functions Reference R3.1, SC30-3533-04. This
> manual can be viewed online through the IBM Publications Center

Last but not least, as I was answering this question the horizonal scroll bar shown in the DBU application really intrigued me. In fact, it made me question the short answer altogether.   But then I ran across the following info in a [post](https://archive.midrange.com/mi400/201003/msg00013.html) to the Midrange.com MI-400 mailing list (whose topic has since been rolled into the [C-400](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/c400-l) list)

```
Horizontal scroll bar:
03 left-arrow
1B scroll-bar shaft
1D scroll-bar slider
(as many 1B and 1D characters as necessary are used to complete the scroll bar)
05 right-arrow
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in edit mode in rpgle- on the left where the number sequence -type w35 (meaning wide start from column 35). You can change the number to your convenient. 01001
01002
01w35